# How to deal with params from form being nil? (NoMethodError)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, filter

So at the top of my view I created a little form which will let the user choose a semester and a field:

```
<%= form_tag '', :method => :get do %>
          <%= collection_select(:semester, :semester_id, Semester.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
          <%= collection_select(:field, :field_id, Field.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
          <%= submit_tag 'Filter' %>
          <% end %>
```

and then the page will generate based on this "filter" to display the subjects with different links. Now for this I am using the following declaration in the Controller:

```
@betterFilteredLinks = Link.where("semester_id = #{params[:semester][:semester_id].to_i} AND field_id = #{params[:semester][:semester_id].to_i}")
```

Which is working all fine if I load the page with the filter applied like this:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/?utf8=✓&semester%5Bsemester_id%5D=2&field%5Bfield_id%5D=1&commit=Filter
```

However if I only load http://0.0.0.0:3000/ it will (naturally) set the params of the filter to `nil` and the page will display an error.

I can't think of a solution to this and I'm not sure where to look. I read that I'm not supposed to set default values for the params? Would that even be possible?

Is there a different way to solve this than entering the view with the params already predefined? I believe I might be doing something fundamentally wrong here but I just learned about the forms and params today..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What would you *like* the *"correct"*  behaviour to be when the URL is entered with no parameters? This is not a trick question; the behaviour can be anything (sensible), but I don't know how to answer your question without knowing the desired behaviour.

Comment: For example, it could be: A meaningful error message (not just "whoops, something went wrong!"); or redirect to another page; or default to a certain `semester_id` (based on what logic?); or *show all* - i.e. don't filter by semester; ...

Comment: use `dig` like `params.dig(:semester, :semester_id)`. But `nil.to_i` gives you `0`, not sure if you want that. Filtering in the Controller is something I would not recommend, perhaps create a new class called `GradeFilter`, or give it a proper name. And perhaps build your query depending on wether the param is present or not, like `@betterFilteredLinks = Link.order(:semester_id)`, `@betterFilteredLinks.where(semester_id: semester_id) if semester_id`, you first have to set `semester_id` in your class(you could use `dig)`, or pass `params[:semester]` to your new class, well, there are many ways.

Comment: @TomLord oh yes, the correct behaviour with no filter selected should just be that nothing is displayed on the site. The sections on the page will generate based on what filter combination has been chosen. Eg someone choses semester 1 so only the sections with semester_id 1 will be displayed. Therefore if no filter is applied, the page will only display the header.

Comment: @fanta building the query depending on whether the param is present or not is exactly what I want to do! I just didn’t know how to put that in words like this! Thanks! :) I’m going to try dig tomorrow and report back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question quite well, but if what you need is to provide default behavior to nil or incorrect params ( what you should validate too), you can use a private method in the controller, create an object from params info and set this object in the action with a before_action... Something like this:

```
private
def set_full_params_data
  @full_params = {}
  params[:semester].nil? ?  @full_params[:semester_id] = DEFAULT_ID : 
                            @full_params[:semester_id] = params[:semester]
                            [:semester_id]
  ... etc
end
```

And add the

```
before_action :set_full_params_data, only: [:action_name]
```

and in the action use @full_params instead params.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow morning and come back with a result! I believe this is what I was looking for. The issue is that if the params are not set (because the page has been loaded but no filter has been applied yet) rails will spit an error because I’m trying to set params[nil][nil] essentially.

Comment: I did a little different approach and in the view added the line 

`if !params[:semester].nil?`

before generating the sections. This worked as well. Is there a safety issue with this?

Comment: Well, what if the params[:semester] is not nil but has an incorrect value?, you could need to do a few more things with the params that only check nullity, and keep this logic in the controller is a good practice keeping the MVC separation consistentily...

Comment: that’s a good point! Thanks for the thought, I really appreciate your help! :)